# my android app don't close itself

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

When I test my android application on my phone, the application don't want to quit and make a bug on my phone. My little app take 70MB on my phone and still alive all the day...

How can I close it?

Do I have to put a Listner for the button "return" or there is some methods made from the SDK???

Thanks !

**EDIT:
My application still runing, even if I press "HOME" ... this is not normal, is it?**

Comment: you should find out why your "little app" takes 70MB (of what?) on your phone. Also you should be more specific what "won't quit" means...

Comment: Android will stop your app when there is a need for it (when it is running in the background and the used resources are needed by another app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can override onKeyDown function like this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {

         finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tabhosts, do I have to put that code in the main on or every other class?

Comment: you can put in all activities,but i put that only in main activity

Answer (score 7):

Application on mobile aren't meant to quit, because it's against the UX of mobile user.

Have a look at this discussion. [Android: Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2034238/593709)